# Web.config Transform on another configuration file

Tags: asp.net, web-config, slowcheetah

Can you do a web.config transforms on another file like connections.config, nlog.config, app.config in the same way?  I can't seem to find an answer.

```
 <connectionStrings xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=ConnectionString" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(mode)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You could try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Comment: I already added Connections.Release.config and it isn't getting picked up.

Comment: Did u see my answer? It should solve this problem

Answer (score 5):

I have created a Visual Studio add in for just this. It's called SlowCheetah and you can find it at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5.

Comment: I installed the latest version of SlowCheetah on VS2012 to use it with NLog.config but when I right click on NLog.config, I don't get "Add Transform" option. Is there a different way that I don't know of?

Comment: That should be it. What type of project are you using? Did you restart VS?